# Displaying another table field in GridView based on ID of record in another table

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I currently have an SQL Table called Attendance and another table called Student. The attendance Table has the fields: AttendanceID, Date, Present, StudentID and Module ID. My student table has the fields StudentID and Name. One page in my application allows the user to enter the Students ID in a textbox where all the date, present, ModuleID from the Attendance Table are shown in a Gridview for the corresponding StudentID that is entered in the Textbox. Here is my code so far which works:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegisterConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Attendance] WHERE ([StudentID] = @StudentID)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="pnumTextBox" Name="StudentID" 
                            PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                    style="position:absolute; top: 241px; left: 357px; width: 356px;" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AttendanceID" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="AttendanceID" HeaderText="AttendanceID" 
                            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AttendanceID" />
                        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Present" HeaderText="Present" 
                            SortExpression="Present" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="StudentID" 
                            SortExpression="StudentID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ModuleID" HeaderText="ModuleID" 
                            SortExpression="ModuleID" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Along with displaying the AttendanceID, StudentID, ModuleID, Present, and Date, I need to display the Student Name field from the Student Table which has the same ID as entered in the textbox, how do I achieve this? I think it is possible to do this in the SELECT command but Im unsure how. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.AttendanceID,A.Date,A.Present,A.ModuleID,S.StudentID,S.Name
FROM attendance A ,student S
WHERE A.StudentID = S.StudentID
AND S.StudentID = "Your Value from the textbox";
```

**INNER JOIN**

I prefer to use `objectDataSource` rather than `SQLDataSource`.
to separate your layers.and use `parameterized query` to avoid sql injection and validate the user entry.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, but I am only a beginner when it comes to asp.net and MySQL what do you mean use parameterized query to avoid sql injection? Thanks

Comment: you will learn all these concept day by day , don't worry,i means use parameters rather than write a hard query.
Look to this link:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3834501/Parameterized-Queries.htm